# Google Maps Draw Rectangle Over 50+% of World

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

I am in a situation where I need to draw a rectangle that covers well over 50% of the world for geography selection.

Using the default drawing tools in gmaps, it reverses the selection if the width of the rectangle exceeds 50% of the world map. Vertical height does not have that size limitation.

Are there any options to disable this weird behavior or a workaround to circumvent it?

I have tried to use `DragToZoom` with a modified function, but that was cumbersome and clunky.

I have been searching through the API documentation for 2 days and can not find a solution.

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J5zMg/86/) that demonstrates the 50%+ map coverage issue.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'rectanglecomplete', function (rectangle) {
    var position = rectangle.getBounds();
    $('#marker-position').append('rectangle => '+position);
});
```

Comment: I was able to use the polygon tool to cover most of the map.  Maybe try defining your selection as a rectangle-shaped polygon with 6 or 8 points to keep google from wrapping to the shorter distance.  http://imgur.com/9mTjoEi

Comment: i am looking to use the rectangle tool, for it is easier for the end user to click and drag. i will take a shot with a poly and see how that works with my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after i searched the gmaps bug report, i found out it was a 180 degree limitation. using that new term, i was able to find this solution: [How do I draw rectangle covering more than 180 degrees longitude using google maps drawing library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18531652/how-do-i-draw-rectangle-covering-more-than-180-degrees-longitude-using-google-ma)

All i used was the `drawRectangle` within a `mousemove` listener and the `calculateBounds` to get the correct size.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(self.map, 'mousemove', function(e) {
        if (self.select) {
            self.drawRectangle(e.latLng);
        }
    });

    self.calculateBounds = function(newEndPoint) {
        var north = self.startPoint.lat() >= newEndPoint.lat() ? self.startPoint.lat() : newEndPoint.lat();
        var south = self.startPoint.lat() <= newEndPoint.lat() ? self.startPoint.lat() : newEndPoint.lat();
        var sw = new google.maps.LatLng(south, self.startPoint.lng());
        var ne = new google.maps.LatLng(north, newEndPoint.lng());

        return new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw, ne);
    };

    self.drawRectangle = function(newEndPoint) {
        self.rectangle.setBounds(self.calculateBounds(newEndPoint));
        self.rectangle.setMap(self.map);
    };
```